# Jekyll: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, jekyll-theme

I'm new to `Jekyll` and I'm trying to install new themes for my test-project in order to find which one is more suitable.

Basically, this is the procedure I follow:

1. download (or clone) sources the theme to `~/gems/gems/`
2. enter in `~/gems/gems/<new_theme>` directory
3. run `bundle install`
4. if it works, go to my project folder and
5. edit both `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` with the  name
6. run `bundle install`

So far I tried at least 5-6 themes and *none* worked.
Most of the times I get this kind of error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    jekyll (= 4.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (~> 4.0.0)

    jekyll-theme-clean-blog was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.6)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

But I cannot understand it.
`Gemfile.lock` says the version of `jekyll` is 4.0.0
`Gemfile` says the required version of `jekyll` is greater or equal than 4.0.0 -> OK
`jekyll-theme-clean-blog` depens on `jekyll` greater or equal than 3.6 -> OK

So why it fails? I have version 4.0.0 that is greater than 3.6 as stated by the dependency chain.
Where's my fault here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**jekyll-theme-clean-blog was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
  jekyll (~> 3.6)
```

means that Bundler wants to use version `4.0.1` of the `jekyll-theme-clean-blog` but that versions depends on `~> 3.6` of `jekyll`.

`~> 3.6` is a shortcut for `>= 3.6 && < 4.0`. Therefore `jekyll 4.0.0 does not match.

You have two options:

1. Because Bundler already found one of the latest version of `jekyll-theme-clean-blog` and that the latest version still [requires `jekyll ~> 3.8.5`](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-theme-clean-blog) you must downgrade `jekyll` to `~> 3.6` *or*
2. you must get rid of `jekyll-theme-clean-blog` gem at all.

Comment: Got it. I didn't understand the `&& < 4.0` part. There's a lot of theme out there not compatible with the latest `jekyll` release. I'm going to find a newer one.